# How to process first n items and remaining one differently in a observable stream

Tags: java, rx-java

for example,

given a stream of a certain number (m) of numbers (m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6...),  and apply a transformation (2 * i) to first n items (n can be less, equal or larger than m),  apply another transformation (3 * i) to the remaining items.  and

return result : m1*2, m2*2, m3*3, m4*3, m5*3, m6*3... (assuming n=2 here).

I was trying to use take(n) and skip(n) and then concatwith, but looks like take(n) will drop the remaining items in the sequence , and make skip(n) after that return nothing.

Comment: Is that a representative example? In that case, don't you want to zip your m stream with a second stream of n 2s then as many 3s as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share your m's stream, and then merge back together `take()` and `skip()` streams, something like this:

```
    int m = 10;
    int n = 8;
    Observable<Integer> numbersStream = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            .publish();

    Observable<Integer> firstNItemsStream = numbersStream.take(n)
            .map(i -> i * 2);

    Observable<Integer> remainingItemsStream = numbersStream.skip(n)
            .map(i -> i * 3);

    Observable.merge(firstNItemsStream, remainingItemsStream)
            .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("result = " + integer));
    numbersStream.connect();
```

**EDIT:**
As point out by @A.E. Daphne, `share()` will start emitting with the first subscriber, thus second subscriber might miss notification/s if the Observable started already to emit item/s, so in this case there are other possibilities:
**`cache()`** - will reply all cache emitted items and reply them to each new subscriber, but will sacrifice the unsubscription ability, thus need to be used carefully.
**`reply().refCount()`** - will create `Observable` that `reply()` all previous items to each new Subscriber (similar to cache), but will unsubscribe when the last subscriber unsubscribe from it.

In both cases, memory should take into consideration as the `Observable` will cache all emitted items in memory.

**`publish()`** - Additional possibility, without caching all previous items, would be to use `publish()` to create `ConnectableObservable`, and call it's `connect()` method to begin emissions after all required subscribers subscribed, thus will get synchronization and all subscribers will get all notifications correctly.

Comment: will the usage of share() introduce race condition?

Comment: What do you think that? Race where?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right the share operator is not the right fit here, you can either use publish and the connect method or reply().refCount()